# Android detect if your app is running in Samsung Kids Mode

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I need to know if my app is running in Samsung Kids Mode. Is it possible to programmatically check it?

Comment: As far as I know the Samsung Kids Mode is a closed system that runs only specific apps and doesn't have access to the 3rd party apps on the device. So I don't think you can run your app there any way.

Comment: @HedeH As a parent you can add an app this way: go into kids mode settings - > apps -> add -> find the app in the list and select it

Comment: Ooh nice.. thanks for that :)